# Use of undeclared identifier when I want use swift file in objective c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

when I want use swift file in objective c project and I declare an object from swift class, I get "Use of undeclared identifier" error.
the way that I pass:

1. coping swift file in project and type **@objc** before declare swift class
2. create header file in project manually
3. set "**Defines module**" in target to **Yes**
4. set **objective-C bridging header** in **target** to **$(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h**
5. declare **#import "productModuleName-Bridging-Header.h"** in objective-c file
6. use **name_of_swift_class *s = [[name_of_swift_class alloc] init];**

when I want use swift file in step 6 I get "Use of undeclared identifier" error. why?!!! do I have the mistake?

when I test this steps in new project I don't get error but in project that I want it return error.

thank you for your help

Comment: You could also get this error when placing 'MyProject-Swift.h' within  #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED or #if DEBUG - then it works in simulator but not when building a release..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at **Step 5** You should not be importing **"productModuleName-Bridging-Header.h"** instead you should be importing **"productModuleName-Swift.h"**

P.S- After making this change clean your project, clear your derived data and build it. It will work. Hope it helps :)